# How to get data based on username in cube js

Tags: javascript, sql, mongodb, cube.js

**DEFINITION**

I have connected my cube js backend to mongodb. I am storing documents inside my mongo db database in a following way.

**THIS IS HOW MY DOCUMENT LOOKS LIKE IN MONGO DB**

```
{
  anonymousId: "bdee014b-09e1-4d79-bcf1-c3cc91cd4101"
  user: "abc"
  url: "/index"
  eventType: "pageView"
  date: "22-08-2020"
  time: "20:33:9"
  data: "some data"
}
```

So now let us assume that I have **10 documents** in my mongodb collection in which 5 documents belong to **user: "abc"** and 5 documents belong to **user: "xyz"**.

**HOW I GET THE DATA RIGHT NOW IN THE BROWSER CONSOLE IS SHOWN BELOW**

```
{
 annotation: {measures: {,…},…}
 data: [{Events.user: "xyz",…}, {Events.user: "xyz",…}, {Events.user: "xyz",…},…]
 0: {Events.user: "xyz",…}
 1: {Events.user: "xyz",…}
 2: {Events.user: "xyz",…}
 3: {Events.user: "abc",…}
 4: {Events.user: "abc",…}
 5: {Events.user: "xyz",…}
 lastRefreshTime: "2020-08-22T15:23:53.547Z"
 query: {measures: ["Events.pageView", "Events.buttonClick"], dimensions: ["Events.user", 
 "Events.allData"],…}
 refreshKeyValues: [[{unix_timestamp(): 1598109833}]]
 usedPreAggregations: {}
}
```

Here you can see in the data array that i get back as a response from the cube js backend has 6 objects in **4** of them belong to user **XYZ** and **2** of them belong to **ABC**.

**MY CUBE.JS SCHEMA**

```
cube(`Events`, {

sql: `SELECT * FROM test.events`,

refreshKey: {
    sql: `SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`
},

measures: {
    count: {
        type: `count`
    },

    pageView: {
        type: `count`,
        filters: [
            { sql: `${eventType} = 'pageView'` }
        ]
    },

    buttonClick: {
        type: `count`,
        filters: [
            { sql: `${eventType} = 'buttonClicked'` }
        ]
    }
},

dimensions: {

    anonymousId: {
        sql: `anonymousId`,
        type: `string`
    },

    url: {
        sql: `url`,
        type: `string`
    },

    user: {
        sql: `user`,
        type: `string`
    },

    allData: {
        sql: `data`,
        type: `string`
    },

    eventType: {
        sql: `eventType`,
        type: `string`
    },

    referrer: {
        sql: `referrer`,
        type: `string`
    },

 }

});
```

**QUESTION**

How can i **segregate** or we can say **group data** depending upon the user. What i mean is that i want the data to return two arrays for two different users. Lets say if **xyz** has 2 documents an array of 2 documents for that very user should be returned and **abc** has 4 documents an array of 4 documents should be returned.

They should not be returned combined. **abc's data should be returned seperately** and **xyz's data should be returned seperately.**

2 USERS SHOULD MAINTAIN 2 DIFFERENT ARRAYS

**EXPECTATION**

A trick or a way by which we write the schema in achieving this behavior,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [User Context](https://cube.dev/docs/cube#context-variables-user-context) or queryTransformer or [Multitenant Compile Context](https://cube.dev/docs/multitenancy-setup#user-context-vs-multitenant-compile-context), these three functions allow you to implement data access based on authorization data.

[queryTransformer](https://cube.dev/docs/multitenancy-setup#user-context-vs-query-transformer) is a little more complicated, but it will allow you to customize access control more flexibly. It is better suited for complex cases.